# Show that this subset is compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be any topological space such that contains a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that $x_n \to x$

Show that $A=\{ x_n |  \, n\in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{x\}$ is a compact subset of $X$.

**My attempts:** I know that a space is compact iff all nets have a convergent subnet and in my opinion if a net in $A$ contains an infinite number of distint points, it must converge to $x$, else at least one of the points must be repeated in the net so we can take those points as a convergent subnet.

Am I on the right way? If so, how can I write it formally?

Comment: Use the definition in terms of open covers to prove it.

Comment: @DanielFischer using that, i think it is intuitive that the open set which covers $x$ will conver almost all points, in a way such that the collection of points not convered by the open set which covers $x$ is finite. But how can I write that formally?

Comment: If you take any example of open covers, remember that all elements of A with a high enough index n will be in the cover that the limit is in.

Comment: @Bernd yes,that is the idea I have in mind, what I need help with is how to write it formally

Comment: @Trollkemada The definition of convergence gives you that directly. Any open set containing $x$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, so it contains ... $x_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with convergent subnets and in my conception a *compact set* is characterized by the fact that every open cover of it has a finite subcover. If $\mathcal U$ denotes such a cover of $A$ and $x\in U\in \mathcal U$ then $x_n\in U$ for $n$ large enough. The number of elements $x_n$ not in $U$ is finite and for each there is a $U_n \in \mathcal U$ that contains it. This results in a finite subcover containing $A$. So $A$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Nets are nasty, avoid them if possible. The answer by drhab gives the most reasonable solution.

Normally I do not give complete solutions to homework questions. Here I do it, because neither of the two solutions is one that you should hand in anyway.

First, that $x_n\to x$ means that the map $n\to x_n$, $\infty\to x$ from the one-point-compactification of $\mathbb N$ to $X$ is continuous. The subset $A$ is the image of this map and compact, since the one-point-compactification is actually compact.

Ok, now to nets. Have you looked at the definition of a sub-net? It is the reason why one might decide not to want to bother with them. Well, let $(a_j)_{j\in D}$ be our net in $A$. If $x_m$ is not an accumulation point of $a$, then there is a $j_m\in D$ such that $a_k\ne x_m$ for all $k\ge j_m$. So if no $x_m$ is an accumulation point, then we can do the following. We equip $D\times\mathbb N$ with the product order and for each $(j,m)\in D\times\mathbb N$ we choose $k_{j,m}\in D$ such that $k_{j,m}\ge j$ and $k_{j,m}\ge j_n$ for all $n\le m$. Now $(a_{k_{j,m}})_{(j,m)\in D\times\mathbb N}$ is a sub-net of $(a_j)_{j\in D}$. We show that it converges to $x$. Let $U$ be a neighbourhood of $x$. Choose $m$ such that $x_n\in U$ for all $n>m$. Let $j\in D$ be arbitrary. Then for any $(j',m')\ge(j,m)$ we have $k_{j',m'}\ge j_n$ for all $n\le m$ and hence $a_{k_{j',m'}}\in A\setminus\{x_n\colon n\le m\}\subset U$. This shows that the sub-net converges to $x$. Now, if there an $x_n$ is an accumulation point of $(a_j)_{j\in D}$, then there is a sub-net which converges to $x_n$.

This formalises, I think, your intuition. But, really?